Conditionally add certain Middlewares in certain routes NEXT JS
Based on the documentation, all the middlewares are added in a single file called middleware.ts.
And most of the time, the middlewares are all added to all paths
middleware1(middleware2(middleware3))

This is what I did
Middleware.ts
import { NextFetchEvent, NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { updateSession } from "@/utils/supabase/middleware";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { withHeaders } from "./middleware/withHeader";
import { withLogging } from "./middleware/withLogging";
import { StackMiddleware } from "./middleware/stackMiddleware";

export async function middleware(
  request: NextRequest,
  resposne: NextResponse,
  event: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/test")) {
    // return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/about-2", request.url));
    const middlewares = [withLogging, withHeaders];
    StackMiddleware(middlewares);
  }
  const themePreference = response.cookies.get("theme");
  if (!themePreference) {
    response.cookies.set("theme", "dark");
  }
  await updateSession(request);
  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     * Feel free to modify this pattern to include more paths.
     */
    "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
  ],
};

StackMiddleware.ts
import { NextMiddleware, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";

export function StackMiddleware(
  functions: MiddlewareFactory[] = [],
  index = 0
): NextMiddleware {
  const current = functions[index];
  //Base case
  if (current) {
    const next = StackMiddleware(functions, index + 1);
    return current(next);
  }
  return () => NextResponse.next();
}

How do I conditionally add middleware to certain routes ? In this example how do I stack middleware for /test ?
Thank you

I believe you use the matcher to decide where the middleware should run. Maybe you can construct multiple matchers? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matching-paths

The matcher is telling which routes should it skip. What I'm asking is multiple middlewares like middleware1,middleware2,middleware3. I want  /test to have middleware1 and middleware3 but my /profile , I want middleware1, middleware2 and middleware3 to be applied.

Found the Solution for it.
First define StackMiddleware.ts , this is where you can chain multiple middlewares. This function accepts an array of middleware functions and returns a single combined middleware function.
app/Middleware/types.ts
import { NextMiddleware } from "next/server";

export type MiddlewareFactory = (middleware: NextMiddleware) => NextMiddleware;

app/Middleware/StackMiddleware.ts
import { NextMiddleware, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";

export function StackMiddleware(
  functions: MiddlewareFactory[] = [],
  index = 0
): NextMiddleware {
  const current = functions[index];
  //Base case
  if (current) {
    const next = StackMiddleware(functions, index + 1);
    return current(next);
  }
  return () => NextResponse.next();
}

app/Middleware/WithHeader.ts
import { NextFetchEvent, NextMiddleware, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";
export const withHeaders: MiddlewareFactory = (next: NextMiddleware) => {
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    const res = await next(request, _next);
    if (res) {
      res.headers.set("x-content-type-options", "nosniff");
      res.headers.set("x-dns-prefetch-control", "false");
      res.headers.set("x-download-options", "noopen");
      res.headers.set("x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN");
      console.log(res.headers);
    }
    return res;
  };
};

app/Middleware/WithLogging.ts
// middleware/withLogging.ts
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";
export const withLogging: MiddlewareFactory = (next) => {
  console.log("WITH LOGGING !");
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    console.log("Log some data here", request.nextUrl.pathname);
    return next(request, _next);
  };
};

So this is how we use it in middleware.ts
import { NextFetchEvent, NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { withHeaders } from "./middleware/withHeader";
import { withLogging } from "./middleware/withLogging";
import { StackMiddleware } from "./middleware/stackMiddleware";
import { MiddlewareFactory } from "./middleware/types";
import { randomMiddleware } from "./middleware/randomMiddleware"; //another middleware i created

//We define our routes here
const routeMiddlewares: { [key: string]: MiddlewareFactory[] } = {
  "/test": [withLogging, withHeaders], //These are the middlewares we want the route to go through
  "/profile": [withLogging, randomMiddleware],
  // Add other routes and their specific middlewares here
};

export async function middleware(
  request: NextRequest,
  resposne: NextResponse,
  event: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  for (const route in routeMiddlewares) {
    if (path.startsWith(route)) {
      const middlewares = routeMiddlewares[route];
      const stackMiddleware = StackMiddleware(middlewares);
      return stackMiddleware(request, event);
    }
  }
  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     * Feel free to modify this pattern to include more paths.
     */
    "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
  ],
};

Now if we access test route, it will go through withLogging & withHeaders Middleware. If we access profile route, it will go through withLogging and randomMiddleware only but it will NOT go through withHeaders Middleware.

I think it is like this:
Define multiple middlewares in one file:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

function middlewareX(request: NextRequest) {
  // Logic for middleware X
  console.log('Middleware X executed')
  return NextResponse.next()
}

function middlewareY(request: NextRequest) {
  // Logic for middleware Y
  console.log('Middleware Y executed')
  return NextResponse.next()
}

Define your main middleware file conditionally:
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

  // Routes for middleware X
  if (pathname.startsWith('/a') || pathname.startsWith('/b') || pathname.startsWith('/c')) {
    return middlewareX(request)
  }

  // Routes for middleware Y
  if (pathname.startsWith('/d') || pathname.startsWith('/e') || pathname.startsWith('/f')) {
    return middlewareY(request)
  }

  // For all other routes, proceed without middleware
  return NextResponse.next()
}

The matcher can define what to run where:
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/a/:path*', '/b/:path*', '/c/:path*', '/d/:path*', '/e/:path*', '/f/:path*'],
}

This setup will apply middlewareX to routes starting with /a, /b, or /c, and middlewareY to routes starting with /d, /e, or /f.
Alternatively you can use this package: https://github.com/z4nr34l/next-easy-middlewares

I found a better way, thank you.
